# How to wrap using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to wrap global-text and button by creating a div.

```html
<div class="content">
      <div class="fl-module global-button"> </div>
      <div class="fl-module global-text"> </div>
      <div class="fl-module button"> </div>
      <div class="fl-module text"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you think you might do it? What is your attempt. Also, you're question needs a bit more context

Comment: You want to surround the two divs global-button and global-text in a div?

Comment: @epascarello yes,is it possible?

Comment: Use one of these: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+wrap+elements+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @Kinglish i want to wrap global text and button in different div.

Comment: What is the expected result? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What are the problems you have with your approach? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas yes there are possible ways using jquery,i found it on stack,but i wanna use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an element and append it to the place you want it. Select the elements you want to be in that element and append them to that new div.

```js
//Select the elements you want inside
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".global-button, .global-text");

// create the div to wrap your elements
const wrapper = document.createElement("div");

// add it to the DOM
divs[0].before(wrapper);

// insert the elements into the newly created div
divs.forEach(div => wrapper.append(div));
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: .4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="fl-module global-button">a</div>
  <div class="fl-module global-text">b</div>
  <div class="fl-module button">c</div>
  <div class="fl-module text">d</div>
</div>
```

If you have multiple of these, you need to do it slightly different

```js
function wrapIt(parentElem, selectors) {

  //Select the elements you want inside
  const divs = parentElem.querySelectorAll(selectors);

  // create the div to wrap your elements
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");

  // add it to the DOM
  divs[0].before(wrapper);

  // insert the elements into the newly created div
  divs.forEach(div => wrapper.append(div));
}

var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
contents.forEach((content) => wrapIt(content, ".global-button, .global-text"));
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: .4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="fl-module global-button">a</div>
  <div class="fl-module global-text">b</div>
  <div class="fl-module button">c</div>
  <div class="fl-module text">d</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="fl-module global-button">a</div>
  <div class="fl-module global-text">b</div>
  <div class="fl-module button">c</div>
  <div class="fl-module text">d</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="fl-module global-button">a</div>
  <div class="fl-module global-text">b</div>
  <div class="fl-module button">c</div>
  <div class="fl-module text">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, i have a one question,elements become duplicated anyway to prevent that.

Comment: Unclear how elements become duplicated. I guess you left out details from your post.

Comment: Sorry mate i had an error on my code,now it is fixed,your code working like a charm,thank you.

Comment: you are a real gem,i ll try that it will help in the future.